# Which modes allow you to author a document with images in between paragraphs (like editing a rtf/pdf/docx)

Tags: ms-word

How does one write a document like this with emacs? (text paragraphs  with the occasional image inlined)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both [Orgmode](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images.html#Images) and [markdown-mode](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) support displaying images in text documents. The images themselves are not inserted, but rather links to the images are. These links may be configured to display the linked images, or the link text. This can be configured, and both modes allow you to toggle displaying the link text or the image.

In either case, if you are sharing the documents with others, and you want to send them a single file containing both the text and images, you'll need to export to a file format that supports that. For markdown that would be html. Orgmode can export to pdf, html, odt and several other formats. If you want to share the text files themselves, you'll need to also send the image files.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. In org-mode you could do this:

```
file:./somefile.jpg
```

That would link the picture in the same directory to the file. You could also use the exact location of the picture if it is not in the same directory. You can follow the link with a brief description.

```
file:./somefile.jpg my description
```

You can force a line break after the jpg file by adding a space and two back slashes.

```
file:./somefile.jpg \\
my description
```

If you then export to an odt file for example, the picture will be attached in line.

I don't use markdown, so I cannot comment on that.